# Node Transform stream quirk when using Function.bind

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Ran into this Transform stream behavior which I can't quite explain. First the setup:

```
var pass = new require('stream').PassThrough

var numbers = ['one:', 'two:', 'three:', 'four:', 'five:', 'six:', 'seven:', 'eight:', 'nine:', 'ten:']

pass.pipe(process.stdout)
```

OK, now when I write to the stream using a `forEach`, I get the following, expected, behavior:

```
numbers.forEach(function(val) {
  pass.write(val)
})

# one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight:nine:ten:
```

But! If I write to the stream in this ever so slightly different way, I get the following *unexpected* behavior:

```
numbers.forEach(pass.write.bind(pass))

# one:tthfoufivesix:seven:eight:nine:ten:
```

So my question is, why the different outputs? Am I just missing something here?

I'm running `v0.10.30`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

`.forEach` passes multiple arguments to the callback, so when you pass the callback directly, you aren't just passing `val` to the callback, you are also passing the array index and the whole array to `.write`.

#### Long answer:

Your equivalence comparison is wrong:

```
numbers.forEach(pass.write.bind(pass));
```

is *not* the same as

```
numbers.forEach(function(val) {
  pass.write(val)
});
```

it is equivalent to this:

```
numbers.forEach(function() {
  pass.write.apply(pass, arguments);
});
```

or more specifically:

```
numbers.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  pass.write(val, index /* encoding */, array /* cb */);
});
```

When you look at the signature of `.write(chunk, encoding, cb)`, the callback is ignored if it isn't a function, so you are essentially doing `.write(val, index)`. The crazy output arrises because those values get passed into `Buffer` before writing, so you are essentially calling this:

```
numbers.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  pass.write(new Buffer(val, index /* encoding */));
});
```

*that* decomposes into something like this:

```
numbers.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  var b = new Buffer(...);
  b.write(val, index /* encoding */);
  pass.write(b);
});
```

And that is where the magic happens. The signature of `Buffer.prototype.write` is

```
.write(string, [offset], [length], [encoding])
```

Since you passed the encoding as a number instead of an actual encoding, the call using the encoding value as the length instead of the encoding, so you are slicing up the string length based on the array index.

Comment: Doh! OK... I thought it was going to be something like this -_- Thanks!